# Modify Transformerless Power Supplies

Tags: esp8266, transformerless

Based on this article:
https://hackaday.com/2017/04/04/the-shocking-truth-about-transformerless-power-supplies/

I have some rf wireless plug outless which use transformerless power supply.

I would like to build in an ESP32 (3.3v) in it. I don't know currently what output the transformerless powersupply in these produce but I seen some 24V relays so I have to check.

My questions are:

1, Regardless that it is not safe to connect an ESP32 through the mains as the article explains, is the output of a TPS fine grain enough to power an ESP?

2, In the article it states: "excess current is shunted to ground when the load draws less than the 25 milliamps", an ESP32 power consumption is between 100-250 mA (using wifi) why does it matter how much my load drains?
For example let's assume that this circuit I wan't to modify would output 3.3V to the board, would I still need to modify it if my load is different?

3, Is there some online calculator for TPSes where I can put in my load value and desired voltages and it will calculate what cap and resistor(s) will I need?

Thanks

Comment: It's not safe for a beginner so if you have to ask, you're a beginner so don't use it.

Comment: Just use a USB phone "charger" and a 3.3V LDO regulator. Stay safe.

Comment: I agree. A phone charger costs just $1. Add an AMS1117-3.3 or a TL431 and 2N2222. A lot less headache and portable, besides being safer. Alternately, one can use a 6V step down transformer. In some parts of the world these may cost just 50 cents.

Comment: ESPs can use as much as 200ma and as little as 5ma, making it hard to design an efficient capacitive dropper that can handle the full range of currents needed.

Comment: Google "HLK-PM03". You can get like 5 pcs for $10 and be done with it. Note: ESP32 can draw up to 500mA(!) when transmitting.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://daycounter.com/Circuits/Transformerless-Power-Supplies/Transformerless-Power-Supplies.phtml) is an online calculator for TPS in various configurations.

Play with the values and you will see that for 250mA load you will need a non polarised capacitor with a value over 4.7uf at 400V. At a quick search the capacitor I found is 25/25/35mm in volume and costs 3$.

The TPS will have a low efficiency and your project very hard to debug.

Please follow Wesley's and Indraneel's  advice and use a phone USB charger or something similar, some simple chargers can be tricked to output 3,3V It will be not only cheaper but also smaller , safer and will heat less.